# Why is the clicked() signal for the QPieSlice not emitted?

Tags: qt, charts, signals

I'm using Qt charts module to draw a Nested Donuts chart just like the example in Qt Charts. 
[image]

And I want every components (QPieSlice) response to the mouse event, the hovered() signals work well, however, the clicked() signals only work for the QpieSlices in the last added QPieSerie. It seems other QpieSlices do not emit the signals, since if I explicitly call the clicked() function, the slot response correctly.
 This piece of code shows the issue

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent){
    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView;
    QChart *chart = chartView->chart();

    for (int i = 0; i < donutCount; i++) {
    QPieSeries *donut = new QPieSeries;
    donut->setHoleSize(minSize + i * (maxSize - minSize) / donutCount);
    donut->setPieSize(minSize + (i + 1) * (maxSize - minSize) / donutCount);
    int sliceCount = 3 + qrand() % 3;
    for (int j = 0; j < sliceCount; j++) {
        qreal value = 100 + qrand() % 100;
        QPieSlice *slice = new QPieSlice(QString("%1").arg(value), value);
        slice->setLabelVisible(true);
        slice->setLabelColor(Qt::white);
        slice->setLabelPosition(QPieSlice::LabelInsideTangential);
        connect(slice, SIGNAL(hovered(bool)), this, SLOT(explodeSlice(bool)));
        connect(slice, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(selected()));
        donut->append(slice);
    }
    m_donuts.append(donut);
    chartView->chart()->addSeries(donut);
}

void Widget::selected()
{
    QPieSlice *slice = qobject_cast<QPieSlice *>(sender());
    cout << slice->label().toStdString() << endl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the QPieSeries instead. That would save you a lot of connects and the typecast as well. `QPieSeries::clicked(QPieSlice*)`

Comment: @Lifeisabug yes, I have tried this method, but it still doesn't work and shows the same problem.